# Combine array in PHP with values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Consider the below multi dimension array:

```
Array
(
[submit] => yes
[id] => 
[booking_id] => 
[booking_type_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 171
        [1] => 58
    )

[value] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [1] => 46
    )

)
```

How do I combine it so that that the booking_type_id and value arrays are in one array with the same values:

```
Array
(
    [new_values] => Array
        (
            [171] => 23
            [58] => 46
        )

)
```

I have tried array_merge and array_combine, but I can't get it to keep the keys? I have also tried to loop through and add to a new array.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried already -- the loop through/add to new array should work; there may just be a bug in your implementation.

Comment: Can you show the expected Array structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you use `array_combine`. That should work for the structure you want. Example below:

```
$multi = array(
    'submit'          => 'yes',
    'id'              => '',    
    'booking_id'      => '', 
    'booking_type_id' => array( 171, 58 ),
    'value'           => array( 23, 46 ),
);

$combined = array_combine( $multi['booking_type_id'], $multi['value'] );
```

Comment: Pleased I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `array_combine()` function like this:

```
$array['new_values'] = array_combine($array['booking_type_id'], $array['new_values']);
```

Comment: probably the most easy way to accomplish this. You just have to be sure that the number of elements is the same in each array.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to loop through the `booking_type_id` array and correlate those values in a new array with:

```
$array_1['booking_type_id'] = array(171,58);
$array_1['value'] = array(23,46);

$array_2 = array(); // new combined array

foreach ($array_1['booking_type_id'] as $key => $value) {
    $array_2[$value] = $array_1['value'][$key];
}
```

With the result being:

```
Array
(
    [171] => 23
    [58] => 46
)
```

**UPDATE:**

As others have already noted you can also accomplish the same with [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$array_2 = array_combine( $array_1['booking_type_id'], $array_1['value'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $new_values = array();
    while($i < count($your_array['booking_type_id']))
    {
        $new_values['new_values'][$your_array['booking_type_id'][$i]] = 
$your_array['value'];
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
        'submit' => "yes",
        'id' => NULL,
        'booking_id' => NULL,
        'booking_type_id' => array(
                0 => 171,
                1 => 58
        ),  
        'value' => array(
                0 => 23,
                1 => 46
        )

);


$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr['booking_type_id'] as $key=>$value){

    $new_arr[$value] = $arr['value'][$key];

}
$arr['new_values'] =  $new_arr;

echo"<pre>";print_r($arr);
```

**Result will be**

```
Array
(
[submit] => yes
[id] => 
[booking_id] => 
[booking_type_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 171
        [1] => 58
    )

[value] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [1] => 46
    )

[new_values] => Array
    (
        [171] => 23
        [58] => 46
    )

)
```